# What happens if you run out of Beans?

Tags: bohnanza

What happens if at the beginning of my turn I have no Beans left in my hand to plant because I traded them all away on other people's turns?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The official [Rio Grand Games](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_36_gameRules.pdf)  rules cover this eventuality (page 4) the last sentence under **Plant Bean Cards**

> If the Active Player has no cards in hand, he omits this step.

I have no access to the Amigo Games version, or the German version of the rules. [The Game Cabinet](http://gamecabinet.com/rules/Bohnanza3.html) site does have a translation:

> **Playing Bean Cards** - You must play the first card dealt to you on to one of your fields, **unless you hold no cards.**

You just skip the first step, since you are unable to fulfill the conditions.